# inserting if in a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i do something like this ?

```
SELECT    (IF(SUM(Costo) > 0) SUM(Costo) ELSE 0) AS Expr1
FROM         TDP_NotaSpeseSezB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a CASE statement.

```
Select 
  CASE WHEN SUM(Costo) > 0 THEN SUM(Costo) 
  ELSE 0 
  END 'Expr1'
FROM
  TDP_NotaSpeseSezB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use case statement like this:

```
SELECT case when sum(Costo)> 0 then sum(Costo) 
       else 0 end as Expr1 
FROM TDP_NotaSpeseSezB
```

[CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN SUM(Costo) > 0 THEN SUM(Costo) ELSE 0 END AS Expr1
FROM     TDP_NotaSpeseSezB
```

Other major engines support this syntax:

```
SELECT  GREATEST(SUM(Costo), 0)
FROM     TDP_NotaSpeseSezB
```

`SQL Server`, however, does not.